# How do I get docker-engine dependency libsystemd-journal0 installed on Xenial (16.04.1 LTS)?

Tags: 16.04, docker

Getting this installed is critical in our move to Ubuntu from Mint 17.

So I've seen this:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20698libsystemd-journal0

..which references this page:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libsystemd-journal0/download

...but there's no similar information for xenial:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libsystemd-journal0/download

I've tried adding this line to the sources file:

`deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu xenial main`

I've also tried manually downloading and installing

`libsystemd-journal0_204-5ubuntu20_i386.deb`

...but the system silently doesn't install it.

Comment: you can refer the following link to resolve the issue also steps to install docker-engine and dependencies, http://mytecharticle.com/package-docker-engine-has-no-installation-candidate/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently this is the solution.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: The problem with link only answers is that eventually they stop working. That guide fails with this message: *WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!  `docker-ce`*